# Passing data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app, I'm building a recipe list for foods. The first view controller has a tableview that stores the recipe's name and photo. This name and photo are set in the second view controller via segue.

Here it is:

[image: first vc]

[image: second vc]

As you can see, the second view controller has a How To Do button, that will lead to a third viewController in which I'll set some text via UITextView.

What I want to do is somehow save this text for later, when I tap the designated cell, it will display info like this:

[image]

Under the image should have the text I set, but I can't find a way to properly save it and retrieve later. Could someone help me with this? Is CoreData the right way to do this? Sorry for any mistakes, I'm trying to find my way to Swift :)

Comment: You should somehow store your data. Your data will be dismissed after closing your application. So you should save your data via CoreData etc...

Comment: That's not what I meant haha I stored some information already using NSKeyedArchiver. What I need to know is if stored information with coredata or nskeyedarchiver can be retrieved anytime, anywhere in the application. I tried to save it with nskeyedarchiver but couldn't retrieve it from the third vc, which let me think if it can be accessed anywhere anytime. Apple docs are sometimes confusing and hard to understand. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well, I would just use Core Data for this. Create an entity `Food` with attributes storing the name, imagename, and a string for "how to do". You can fetch this information anywhere in your app and fairly easy to combine it with a table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `CoreData` for this, and yes, you can access this data anywhere in the app.

---

Explaining how to implement `CoreData` can end up in quite a big answer though! Instead I will recommend you to watch the following video from a Stanford course on iOS and CoreData. I've used this myself and I can definitely recommend it! It will teach you both how to implement it and the logic behind.

[Stanford University Developing iOS 7 Apps: Lecture 12 - Documents and Core Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z5-2tZrbPM)

Also, the following video in the series will be quite relevant for you, which explains how to hook up `CoreData` in a smart way with a `UITableView` (since you have a lot of `UITableView`s in your app)

[Stanford University Developing iOS 7 Apps: Lecture 13 - Core Data and Table View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2sZ9IjDBzs)

Comment: Not yet, lacking the time to watch it. I'll try it tonight and let you know how I went!

Comment: I'm watching the video from standford University. I see it's all set for objective-c. Is it the same thing to Swift, just adapting the syntax, or does it change anything else?

Comment: Sorry about that, I remembered it being in Swift. But yes, it's more or less just adopting the syntax.

If you want some simple premade code for the `NSManagedObjectContext`, then you can create a new test project and tick of the box `use core data`. This will create some boilerplate code in your `AppDelegate` that you can copy/paste over :)

Comment: Ok! I'll accept your answer here! I'm watching that video from standford. Pretty cool actually, thanks for sharing it! Any doubt I'll scream your name! :D